# How to draw the dotted style for braces?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pst-node,pstricks-add,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=1.5cm,opacity=.5}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(6,6)
    \pnodes(0,0){O}(4,0){B}(0,4){A}
    \pnodes(0.75,0){Q}(2.75,0){W}
    \pnodes(0,0.75){T}(0,2){R}
    \pnodes(Q|R){D}(W|T){E}(B|A){BA}
    %%%%
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linestyle=none](A)(D)(R)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linestyle=none](D)(Q|T)(E)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linestyle=none](E)(W)(B)
    \psLineSegments(O)(W)(B)(B|A)
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt,labelsep=.1}
    \ncline[linecolor=blue!50]{O}{T} \naput{a} % a
    \pcline[linecolor=blue!50](A)(Q|A) \naput{a} % a
    \pcline[linecolor=orange](R)(A) \naput{b} % b
    \pcline[linecolor=orange](Q|A)(W|A) \naput{b} % b
    \pcline[linecolor=green](T)(R) \naput{c} % c
    \pcline[linecolor=green](W|A)(B|A) \naput{c} % c
    \psLineSegments[linewidth=.7pt,
                    linestyle=dashed,
                    dash=0.05 0.05]%
            (T)(B|T)(R)(B|R)(Q)(Q|A)(W)(W|A)
    \psLineSegments[linecolor=green](W)(B)(Q|T)(D)
    \psLineSegments[linecolor=blue!70](R)(D)(W)(E)
    \psline[linecolor=orange](Q|T)(E)
    %%%% Labels
    \psset{nrot=:U,linewidth=1pt,labelsep=.01}
    \pcline[linecolor=red](A)(B) 
    \naput[npos=.3]{\small \color{red}$\displaystyle (a+b+c)\sqrt{2}$}
    \pcline[linecolor=blue](A)(D) 
    \nbput[npos=.6]{\small \color{blue}$\displaystyle \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$}
    \pcline[linecolor=blue](D)(E) 
    \nbput{\small \color{blue}$\displaystyle \sqrt{b^2+c^2}$}
    \pcline[linecolor=blue](E)(B) 
    \nbput[npos=.4]{\small \color{blue}$\displaystyle \sqrt{c^2+a^2}$}
    %%%% Braces
    \psbrace[braceWidth=.75pt,braceWidthOuter=5pt,braceWidthInner=3pt,% pstricks-add package
             rot=90,ref=tC,nodesepB=3pt,linestyle=dashed](O|0,-.1)(B|0,-.1){\small $a+b+c$}
    \psbrace[braceWidth=.75pt,braceWidthOuter=5pt,braceWidthInner=3pt,
             rot=0,ref=lC,nodesepA=3pt,linestyle=dotted](4.2,0|B)(4.2,0|BA){\small $a+b+c$}
    %%%%
    \uput{3pt}[160](A){$A$}
    \uput{3pt}[0](B){$B$}
    \uput{3pt}[200](O){$0$}
    \uput{3pt}[-130](D){$D$}
    \uput{3pt}[-130](E){$E$}
    \psdots[linecolor=violet](A)(D)(E)(B)
    %%%%
    \uput[90](2,4.5){\psframebox[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan]%
                        {$\displaystyle \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\geq (a+b+c)\sqrt{2}$}}
    \end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to draw braces by the `dotted` or `dashed` style. How can I do?
%%%%

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `pstricks-add` from https://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pstricks-add/  and

```
%%%% Braces
\psbrace[singleline,% pstricks-add package
  rot=90,ref=tC,nodesepB=3pt,linestyle=dashed](O|0,-.1)(B|0,-.1){\small $a+b+c$}
\psbrace[braceWidth=.75pt,singleline,
  rot=0,ref=lC,nodesepA=3pt,linestyle=dotted,dotsep=2pt,
   linewidth=1pt](4.2,0|B)(4.2,0|BA){\small $a+b+c$}
%%%%
```

the optional argument `singleline` (then it cannot not be filled) you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I just recompile my code, and I have a problem as displayed, so, where do I fail?

Comment: Again: I cannot see it!  It is a problem with your viewer!